# File security when storing files as string

Tags: php, string, file, security

I have a quick question about file security.

I have a php script that takes a file from an `<input type="file">` tag and use `file_get_contents()` to store the file data in a variable, are there any security risks that one should be aware of?  Check out the code below:

```
$file_data = file_get_contents($_FILES[file]['tmp_name']);
$file = base64_encode($file_data);
```

This is basicly it, i dont store or move the file, just take its contents and send it to a RESTFUL API as a string.

i have to decide if i should use a completely new webserver to take these requests or if this method is safe on the main server. The site got alot of visitors and i have to assume that people will try to expoit the file field. The API is not a concern, only security concerning server that hosts the script.

Best regards

Comment: You are concerned people will steal an image?

Comment: Hi, no the main concern is security of the server when handling files in this way. File upload is risky, especially when all extensions should be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how big files php is allowed to upload, and memory limit, and the the amount of memory the server has, it can be potentionaly used to crash the server. Use filesize() to check if the size is in reasonable limits.

Answer (score 0):

I see tow  security risks

1. You most sanitize the output & Input content.
2. If you MOST check the file type by validating its content.
3. File path most be Sand-boxed
4. Limit the file size